# ref empty when attempting to map contents to println

Tags: clojure

I'm not sure if I'm running into some sort of race condition, but I was throwing together some test code to test working in a traditional object-oriented paradigm in Clojure, and I ran into some funny behavior. Examine the following code:

```
(def registrar (ref #{}))

(defrecord Person [first-name last-name])

(def rick (->Person "Rick" "James"))
(def charlie (->Person "Charlie" "Murphy"))

(dosync
  (alter registrar conj rick)
  (alter registrar conj charlie))

(defn print-record
  [record]
  (println (format "%s %s", (:first-name record), (:last-name record))))

(defn print-registrar
  "Prints a report of the registrar to stdout"
  [registrar]
  (println "Registrar's Report\n------------------")
  (map print-record registrar))

(let [registrar (deref registrar)]
  (print-registrar registrar))
```

When I run the code in my REPL, all is well: `print-registrar` successfully passes records from the registrar to `print-record` and they are printed as expected, as such:

```
Registrar's Report
------------------
Rick James
Charlie Murphy
(nil nil)
```

But when I try to run the code from the command line, I get the following:

```
Registrar's Report
------------------
```

Is this because `dosync` is called asynchronously or something? When I dump the contents of the registrar before calling `map`, I see what I expect in it, so I'm slightly confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `map` with side-effects isn't usually a good idea, since `map` is lazy, and therefore the side effects won't happen unless something walks through the sequence and forces the side effects (in this case, the repl does it for you).

I think `run!` should be a drop-in replacement here, since `print-record` doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: Hmm, that just led me to `doall`, but `run!` also does what I need it to. This side-effect thing still isn't clear to me, I guess.

Comment: in this case printing is the side-effect.